# How to easily generate JSON out of a running AWS EC2 instance for usage in “run-instances --cli-input-json=”?

Tags: command-line, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, json

How to easily generate json out of a running instance for usage in `run-instances --cli-input-json=`?

The purpose is to recreate instance without too much manual handling or too much json editing.

I would be grateful for your answer.